# Add variable property new value to previous value (javascript)

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Good afternoon. Is it possible to add a new object property value to its previous value?
I have tried the following code but browser returns "Maximum call stack size exceeded". The property translate will be used to drag a chart horizontally. It will shift the data range of an array that will be painted on the canvas chart. Kind regards.

```
function drawChart() {
   .
   .
   .
   tickerData = [..., ..., ...];
   dataLength = tickerData.length;
   barSpace = Number(localStorage.getItem("barspace"));
   barWidth = (0.7 * barSpace).toFixed(1);
   rightSpan = 3 * barSpace;
   barStrokeWidth = 1;
   if(!(dataLength - dragCanvas.translate() > dataLength)) {
      dataLength = dataLength - dragCanvas.translate();
   }
   else {
      dataLength = dataLength;
   }
   .
   .
   .
}
var dragCanvas = {
   isTrue : false,
   drag : [0, 0],
   translate : function() {
      return this.translate() + Math.ceil((this.drag[1] - this.drag[0])/barSpace);
   }
};

function updateChartPaint(e) {
   var pointerX = e.clientX;
   var pointerY = e.clientY;
   if(!dragCanvas.isTrue) {
      dragCanvas.drag[0] = pointerX;
      dragCanvas.drag[1] = pointerX;
   }
   else {
      dragCanvas.drag[1] = pointerX;
      $("#chartCanvas").empty();
      drawChart();
   }
}

document.addEventListener("mousemove", updateChartPaint, false);
document.getElementById("chartCanvas").onmousedown = function() { 
   dragCanvas.isTrue = true;
};
document.getElementById("chartCanvas").onmouseup = function() {
   dragCanvas.isTrue = false;
};
```

Comment: I can't see where you're calling `dragCanvas.translate`, but as soon as you do, you'll get that error because it calls itself unconditionally.

Comment: Hello. I edited the code and explained how translate is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `this.translate()` inside of the `translate` function so it goes into an infinite loop calling itself until eventually the call stack is exceeded.

From the way `translate` is called it looks like the function should be defined like this instead:

```
translate : function() {
  const newTranslate = this.oldTranslate + Math.ceil((this.drag[1] - this.drag[0])/barSpace);
  this.oldTranslate = newTranslate;
  return newTranslate;
}
oldTranslate: 0
```

I assume that `barSpace` is declared outside of the function and will be a valid value. It seems to be set from `localStorage` but if it does not exist, then `Number(localStorage.getItem("barspace"))` will be zero and the return value from `translate` will be `Infinity`. Is that intended?

Also `updateChartPaint` sets a variable called `pointerY` but never uses it. Is it correct that dragging in the Y-axis is ignored and only changes in the X-axis matters?

Comment: Hello. I edited the code and explained how translate is used.

Comment: Yes, barSpace is declared and returned from localStorage the first time the user visits the page and its change is also stored there. The variable pointerY is used every time the mouse pointer position is changed. Everything runs fine except when I try to increment translate property.

Comment: did you try changing the function as shown so it doesn't call itself?

Comment: But that way it doesn't increment the translate property as I want. What I want is something like "translate = translate + .Math.ceil((this.drag[1] - this.drag[0])/barSpace)"

Comment: I adjusted things to have the old translate value a place to live without calling the function within itself

Comment: It is fine now. Now the previous translate is maintained and the new one is added. I Changed `lastTranslate: 0` to `oldTranslate : 0`. Now I need to code the assignment `this.oldTranslate = newTranslate;` to only occur upon the event `onmouseup`. Otherwise the translate increment keeps increasing exponentially when dragging the chart. All the increments should be used only on subsequent `onmousedown` events and not on the present dragging event. Thank you very much for the help. I really got stuck in here and I am not used to javascript.